# How do we get a expression for speed of light $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}$ using Maxwell's equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, maxwell-equations

I am a $12^{th}$ class student in India. I am quite new to these interesting concepts. And, I think I've learnt about electrostatics, magnetism, Maxwell's equations very thoroughly. But, my books doesn't convey satisfactory information about how $c$ is calculated. It just simply that: *using Maxwell's equations, $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}$.*

Also, I've been reading many questions asked about light and photons on this site, stating even the electric wave and magnetic wave are out of phase (which sometimes seems obvious to me), but I lack systemetic resources to learn about them.

I just need some help like how the velocity was calculated or even some resources.

<sup>Probably, this part is more opinion based but can someone please also suggest some good resources to learn these things (free). I heavily rely on sites Khanacademy</sup>

[Clarification after two answers used the differential form of  Maxwell’s equations:]

The main problem is the equations taught to me are different which I find elsewhere:
[image]

[A nice answer to this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466416/how-to-derive-c-1-sqrt-varepsilon-0-mu-0-from-integral-form-of-maxwell-equations) thnx to @Elio Fabri

Comment: Have you checked, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation#The_origin_of_the_electromagnetic_wave_equation?

Comment: @Dvij Mankad I have tried that, but I think all the things I have been taught are quite different.

Comment: @Dvij Mankad Plz look at edit, the problem i face is that things taught to me are not compatible with what i find..

Comment: You learned the integral form of Maxwell's equations. They can also be written in differential form.

Comment: @G. Smith But what is reversed ∆ symbol?

Comment: @PranshuKhandal Ah, as G. Smith said, you are familiar with the integral form of equations which are completely equivalent (up to benign boundary conditions) to the differential form which is used in the Wiki article. You can learn the dictionary between the integral and the differential forms from Chapter 2 and 3 of Feynman Lectures on Physics which are freely available online: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_toc.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol It is a differential operator which you use to form gradients, divergences, and curls.

Comment: I would suggest that you get familiar with the differential form sooner rather than later as they have much more desirable properties. Nonetheless, if you want to get a quick understanding of the electromagnetic waves based on Maxwell equations in the integral formulation, I would suggest you can consult Concepts of Physics by HC Verma. I forgot the exact chapter wherein it is discussed but it must be titled something like "Electromagnetic Waves" etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if I excessively edited the question but most of it appeared redundant. Please feel free to rollback.

Comment: I rolled it back because it ignored the fact that there were two answers which answered the question as originally asked. With your edit, the answers make no sense.

Comment: I have edited the question to indicate that the OP added more AFTER two answers were provided.

Comment: I'm amazed in seeing that apparently nobody is understanding what the
OP is asking for. I'm going to prepare a totally different answer.

Comment: @Elio Fabri does this mean that you have a superb answer?

Comment: @PranshuKhandal Never said that. I only observed that nobody really
tried to deduce $c$ from integral form of Maxwell's equations. Then I
voted for reopening your question, but up to now to no avail. I'm
writing an answer of mine but I'm not yet finished. If when
I'm done your question is still closed I'll post a novel question
and answer it. Please be patient.

Comment: @Elio Fabri Thank you sir :) for being such nice and to value my question. And here, it was my mistake. I was too late to tell others that my problem is of integral form. I really thank you.

Comment: @Elio Fabri also i have started reading feynmanlectures.caltech.edu as told by Dvij Mankad

Comment: @PranshuKhandal Please give a look to my question
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466416/how-to-derive-c-1-sqrt-varepsilon-0-mu-0-from-integral-form-of-maxwell-equations?

Answer (score 6):

You can start from Maxwell's equations with no source in free space (a vacuum).

$\begin{array}{r}{\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}=0} \\ {\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B}=0} \\ {\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}=-\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}} \\ {\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{B}=\mu_{0} \epsilon_{0} \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}}\end{array}$

Taking the curl of the third and forth equations give us 2 equations that show that Maxwell's equations in free space generate $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields that obey the wave equation. Comparing to the wave equation,

$\frac{\partial^{2} \Psi}{\partial x^{2}}=\frac{1}{v^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} \Psi}{\partial t^{2}}$

we can see that

$\frac{1}{v^2} = \mu_0 \epsilon_0$

so that finally

$v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}}$

Comment: Hi! Please check the guidelines for how to answer homework-like questions: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Hi! Sorry - new to here. Is this more like it?

Comment: thnx for help :) but i need a small favor, the maxwell's equations taught to me are a bit different, see in the edit, cab you just plz help me relating them with real equations, thank you for your help

Comment: You are looking at the equations in their integral form. It is common to convert and use them in a differential form (I find them easier to memorise in this form!) - see [WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Maxwell%27s-Equations-into-Differential-Form)

Comment: "hmwphysics" sounds like "h[o]m[ework]physics" ;)

Comment: Haha, they're actually my initials. Great to know they sound like something so wonderful........

Comment: @hmwphysics IMHO, this version is better. Thanks for the edit. Welcome to Physics SE! :)

Comment: thnx for help :)

Answer (score 2):

You find the speed of light by using Maxwell's equations to derive wave equations for the electric and magnetic fields in which you discover that their speed of propagation is $1/\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}$. The details are below.

Start with Maxwell's equations in the absence of any charge density or current density:

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=0$$
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$$
$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}=0$$
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$

You see from the fourth and second equations how a changing electric field induces a magnetic field, and a changing magnetic field induces an electric field, so it seems plausible that they can "keep each other going", with a wave as a result.

To see this, first take the curl of the second and fourth equations:

$$\nabla\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{E})=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\nabla\times\mathbf{B}$$

$$\nabla\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{B})=\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\nabla\times\mathbf{E}$$

Now use the second and fourth equations to replace the curls on the right-hand-sides:

$$\nabla\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{E})=-\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{E}}{\partial t^2}$$

$$\nabla\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{B})=-\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{B}}{\partial t^2}$$

You see that we now have one equation with just $\mathbf{E}$ and one with just$\mathbf{B}$.

There is a mathematical identity for the curl of a curl of any vector field $\mathbf{V}$:

$$\nabla\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{V})=\nabla(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{V})-\nabla^2\mathbf{V}$$

Using this, and the first and third Maxwell equations to get rid of the divergence term, we get

$$\nabla^2\mathbf{E}=\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{E}}{\partial t^2}$$

$$\nabla^2\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{B}}{\partial t^2}$$

These are three-dimensional [wave equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) for each component of the two fields, with the wave velocity equal to $1/\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}$.

Comment: thnx for help :) but i need a small favor, the maxwell's equations taught to me are a bit different, see in the edit, cab you just plz help me relating them with real equations, thank you for your help

Comment: That is not a small favor. Learning how the differential form of Maxwell's equations relates to the integral form that you've learned is not something one can cover in a comment.